# IF & vlookup looking in different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below which does the job I need too. It checks column D to see if the value is bigger than 200, and if it is, then it vlookups in sheet2 to take the corresponding value. However, my approach takes quite time to load because of the loop. Can anyone help me to make the code faster or to have a different approach on it? Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim vlookup As Variant
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long



    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastRow1

    If Cells(i, "D") > 200 Then

    With ws1.Range("g4:g" & lastRow1)
        .Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(a4, " & ws2.Range("a2:b" & lastRow2).Address(1, 1, external:=True) & ", 2, false), text(,))"
        .value = .value
    End With

    Else

    Cells(i, "g") = "Not found"

    End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

put the formula in g4 and copy it down

```
ws1.Range("g4").formula = "=iferror(vlookup(a4, " & ws2.Range("a2:b" & lastRow2).Address(1, 1, external:=True) & ", 2, false), text(,))"
ws1.Range("g4").copy ws1.Range("g4:G" & lastrow1
```

Comment: but how should i set the part which is "not found"? Thanks

Comment: Put it in the iferror portion of your formula   =iferror(vlookup(a4, " & ws2.Range("a2:b" & lastRow2).Address(1, 1, external:=True) & ", 2, false)," & """ & "Not Found" & "")"

Comment: i couldn't succeed to do it. So what I have done was to replace the part of my code which starts from " `For i =4`... until `Next i`" with the code provided by you. Am I doing it wrong? Thanks